# Sorting in map grails

Tags: groovy, dictionary

I have a map like this-

```
def a=["Ak":[data1,col,'ak'],"BH":[data2,col,'bh']]
```

In Another map

```
def b=[:]
```

data is inserted using

```
a.each{key,val->
  def available = val.get(0)
  if (available){
    b[key] = val
  }
}
```

now acording to this map b i need to assign data in table in view.

My problem is i want to check the data size of both `data1` and `data2` and display the data with big size each time  when a user drill down to the view.

Comment: You mean you want to sort the map so the largest `data` value is first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean you want the one with the most data first, you can do (assuming Groovy later than 1.7.9):

```
// dummy data
def data1 = [ 1, 2, 3 ]
def data2 = [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
def col = 'something'

// original map
def a=["Ak":[data1,col,'ak'],"BH":[data2,col,'bh']]


def b = a.findAll { k, v -> v[ 0 ] }               // Keep those with data
         .collectEntries { k, v -> [ k, v[ 0 ] ] } // Make a new map of key:data
         .sort { -it.value.size() }                // Sort it by data size descending
```

Comment: Thanks  i was able to solve it--- i did  a=a.sort{-it.value[0].size()}